# Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

Tags: truffle, rpc

I'm following this tutorial
 https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/a-101-noob-intro-to-programming-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-695d15c1dab4

I have downloaded the code from github repo.
I'm using ganache as a client 
when I do `truffle deploy`

i get that rpc erreur